# Is there a plugin or another way that can help me find out the underlying files of a page/post?

Tags: plugins, posts, custom-field, templates

I have a WordPress website, developed by someone else. I need to make some changes and fix some issues, as the site still has some flaws. For example, there are some fields that need to be changed, but in WP I can't see anything when I try to edit that page/post. Probably there is something custom in the template files of the used Theme. But I can't figure out which CSS or PHP file to check.

Is there a plugin or another way that can help me find out the underlying files of a page/post?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For the template, you can use [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/):

- Activate the plugin and browse the site logged in
- Click the new timings numbers on the admin bar at the top to bring up the bottom pane
- Select 'Template' on the left menu

(or probably other plugins too)

For the CSS files your best bet is to use your browser's debug tools, the Network tab, to see what's loaded.